# How to open JQuery UI popup onclick

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, popup

I have simple html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog({modal: true, height: 590, width: 1005 });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <a id="#OpenDialog" href="#">Click here to open dialog</a>
    <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to have popup content hidden and when click on the link open a dialog.

What I'm wrong with in my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`id` of element is not supposed to have `#` in it if you want to use `jQuery selector` as you used in `$("#OpenDialog").click(`

Change

```
<a id="#OpenDialog" href="#">Click here to open dialog</a>
```

To

```
 <a id="OpenDialog" href="#">Click here to open dialog</a>
```

Comment: No good reason to downvote this one, Adil is correct.  You don't put the # in the id of the actual markup, only when referencing it from a selector such as jQuery or CSS.  In this case, the click handler is never assigned to the element "OpenDialog" because it doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 7):

change  the `id` of the link from `#OpenDialog` to `OpenDialog`

Answer (score 0):

The css link and scripts need to go in the head, not the body.

And as others mentioned, also change the link id from `#OpenDialog` to `OpenDialog`.